# Does having little triceps muscle affect chest excercise?

Tags: strength, gym, bench-press, chest, triceps

I gave recently begun going to the gym and I have been doing chest excercises. Whilst doing these, I gave found my triceps limit me as my stronger right arm can lift much more than my left were I have very little tricep muscle. Can you help with this issue as I am unsure whether or not tricep muscle could be the factor for this.

Excercise I do include barbell bench presses, dumbbell/cable flys and incline bench presses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, yes, triceps can affect your performance on chest exercises. Any exercise that involves some sort of pressing the weight away from you will use your triceps to some degree. However, the wider your grip is, the more emphasis will be placed on your chest.

Flyes are an example of a chest exercise that place very little emphasis on the triceps (except isometrically as the elbow should remain at a fixed angle).

Staying consistent with your benching will be your best option for increasing your tricep size and strength. When doing unilateral work (dumbbells or machines with separate levers for each arm), you should always limit your reps to what you can do with your weaker side as to avoid causing an even larger imbalance.